# Replacing occurences of a specific word if not proceeded by another specific word?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback, negative-lookbehind

I have some text like:

```
*open* blah blah blah blah blah *close* blah blah *open* blah blah *close* blah blah *close*
```

I was wondering how would I remove/replace any occurrences of `*close*` which are not proceeded by `*open*`.

So the above text would become:

```
*open* blah blah blah blah blah *close* blah blah *open* blah blah *close* blah blah
```

I though of maybe using regex with preg_replace - but my regex skills are not that strong?

```
<?php
$string = "*open* blah blah blah blah blah *close* blah blah *open* blah blah *close* blah blah *close*";

$string = preg_replace('#(?<!\*open\*)\*close\*#', '', $string); //this only works for immediate proceedings

echo($string);
?>
```

Code examples would be welcome.

Comment: See [Negative Lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Once you've read this, if you can't get it to work post your code.

Comment: None of your occurrences of _close_ are preceded by _open_, they're all preceded by _blah_. Why don't they all get removed?

Comment: @Barmar I've added my code - but that only works for immediate proceedings, which is not always the case (there's likely going to be some text in-between - this is what I'm struggling to integrate in the regex).

Comment: As I said, your question isn't very clear. If you don't mean "immediately preceding", then ALL the occurrences of "close" are preceded by "open". I guess you actually mean when there's no "open" between two occurrences of "close" you want to remove the second one, is that it?

Comment: @Barmar Yes that is correct.

Comment: @Barmar I would say they're looking for unmatched tags... if you treat \*open\* and \*close\* as tags.

Comment: Unfortunately, regular expressions are very poor for searching for matching/unmatching elements.

Comment: You should tokenise the input instead of using regular expressions.  See http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php for a starting point.

Comment: You could potentially (I'm guessing) run into a problem with nested elements `\*open\* blah \*open\* blah blah \*close\* blah \*close\*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done without regex via the following code:

```
$openTag = '*open*';
$closeTag = '*close*';
$openTagLength = mb_strlen($openTag);
$closeTagLength = mb_strlen($closeTag);

$subj = '*open* blah blah blah blah blah *close* blah blah *open* blah blah *close* blah blah *close*';
$len = mb_strlen($subj);
$isOpened = false;
$res = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; )
{
    if (mb_substr($subj, $i, $openTagLength) === $openTag) {
        // found open tag
        $res .= $openTag;
        $isOpened = true;
        $i += $openTagLength;
    } elseif (mb_substr($subj, $i, $closeTagLength) === $closeTag) {
        // found close tag
        if ($isOpened) {
            $res .= $closeTag;
        } // else skip
        $isOpened = false;
        $i += $closeTagLength;
    } else {
        // non-tag
        $res .= mb_substr($subj, $i, 1);
        $i++;
    }
}
echo $res;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
    $pattern = "/(\\*open\\*.*?\\*close\\*)/";
    $target = "*close* *close* *open* blah blah blah blah blah *close* blah blah *open* blah blah *close* blah blah *close* *close* *open* *open* *close* ";

    $prevMatchEndIndex = 0;
    $matches = array();
    $lastMatchEndIndex = 0;
    $resultParts = array();
    while(preg_match($pattern, $target, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $prevMatchEndIndex)) {
        $matchedString = $matches[0][0];
        $matchStartIndex = $matches[0][1];
        $matchEndIndex = $matchStartIndex + strlen($matchedString) + 1;

        $unmatchedString = substr($target, $prevMatchEndIndex, $matchStartIndex - $prevMatchEndIndex);

        $unmatchedString = preg_replace("/\\s*\\*close\\*\\s*/", " ", $unmatchedString);

        $resultParts[] = trim($unmatchedString);
        $resultParts[] = trim($matchedString);

        $prevMatchEndIndex = $matchEndIndex;
        $lastMatchEndIndex = $matchEndIndex;
    }

    $lastUnmatchedPart = substr($target, $lastMatchEndIndex);
    $lastUnmatchedPart = preg_replace("/\\s*\\*close\\*\\s*/", " ", $lastUnmatchedPart);
    $resultParts[] = $lastUnmatchedPart;    

    echo $target . "<br />";
    echo join($resultParts, " ");
```

Comment: This example doesn't remove the last unmatched close. Output from the OP's provided string:
`*open* blah blah blah blah blah *close* blah blah *open* blah blah *close* blah blah *close*`

Comment: `&$matches` throws a `Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed` fatal error in the latest version of PHP. Forgot to mention it before. If you delete the `&` it works perfectly.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ: Right again. Thanks. I have stopped developing in PHP for more than two years now. That's not an excuse though. Couldn't ignore the question though as basically it was about regex, solved it in Java, ported to PHP using the online PHP manual.